# How to display wp_nav_menu() conditionally only when not on a 404 page?

Tags: theme-development, menus, 404-error

I made a custom design for my site. On my header i put my navigation so everytime i call the header the navigation will be called to, so that i would not be calling it all the time.
But now i have a problem, on my 404 PAGE , i don't want to include the navigation, but if i don't include the header the themes won't play. SO how can i do this?. Any ideas is greatly and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `<?php if( !is_404() ) : ?>` before your navigation and `<?php endif; ?>` after your navigation and VIOLA! It's gone!

Comment: Yeah, And that was Awsomely greatly and highly APPRECIATED.

Comment: Even shorter: `! is_404() and wp_nav_menu();`

Comment: Is there somewhere to find a list of all the pages that function will work with? I replaced "404" with "home", and it worked. But what else will it work with?

Comment: @jag2007 http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags when in doubt, codex.